# How can I enlarge an object so that the new object's surface is 1 cm apart from the initial surface?

Tags: scale

I am very new to Blender. I have an irregular-shaped object which is a tumor (Figure 1)[image]. In order to completely remove the tumor from patient's body, some healthy-looking structures around the tumor also needs to be taken together with the tumor. The margin of the actual removal is 1 cm away from tumor's surface in all aspects (Figure 2)[image]. The hand-drawn images are used for illustration

I have done the segmentation and reconstructed tumor on Blender (Figure 3 - don't worry about the cubical part, it's not important)[image]. Now I would like to develop the removal mass from the tumor by increasing the tumor object size so that the new object surface will be 1 cm away from the tumor object surface. Could you please show me how to do that?

Thank you very much

Comment: Hello :). If it's a 3D object, simply used the Solidify modifier set to 1cm

Comment: you can also try Alt S the Fatten/Shrink, the problem being that some faces could overlap but it may be ok for you

Comment: Thank you both of you. I have tried Solifiy modifier and it works well. I really appreciate your help.